# AngularJS + PHP + MySQL to display data from database

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, database, templating

Can somebody tell me what am I missing here for the code to display data from my database? Much appreciated!

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en" ng-app="VinylApp"> 
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">    
      <title>Vinyl Record Store</title> 
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="script.js"></script><script src="app.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
   </head>

   <body>
     <div ng-app="VinyApp" ng-controller="VinylListController">

       <table>
         <tr ng-repeat="vinyl in vinyls">
           <td>{{vinyl.Vinyl_ID}}</td>
           <td>{{vinyl.VinylName}}</td>
           <td>{{vinyl.Artist}}</td>
           <td>{{vinyl.Price}}</td>
         </tr>
       </table>
     </div> 
   </body> 
 </html>
```

JS

```
var app= angular.module('VinylApp', []);
app.controller('VinylListController', function($scope, $http){
  $http.get("db_con.php")
  .then(function(response){
    $scope.vinyls = response.data.records;     
  });
});
```

PHP

```
<?php 
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); 
  header("Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8");

  $conn = new mysqli("myServer","myUser", "myPassword", "Northwind");
  $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM vinyl");
  $outp= "";
  while($rs=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    if ($outp != "") {$outp .= ",";}
    $outp .= '{"VinylID":"'  . $rs["VinylID"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"VinylName":"'   . $rs["VinylName"]        . '",';
    $outp .= '"Artist":"'. $rs["Artist"]     . '",';
    $outp .= '"Price":"'. $rs["Price"]     . '"}'; } $outp ='{"records":['.$outp.']}'; $conn->close();

    echo($outp); 
  }

?>
```

Comment: If you browse to the `db_con.php`file what is the response you see? Did you chech the console.log for any errors?

Comment: Your PHP code isnt valid. The handlebar `echo($outp); }` and the end is breaking your code.

Comment: Currently I get nothing on my screen and console isn't showing any. Just looking at network status now too, trying to debug it for some time now. Should I replace it with print($outp);} instead?

Comment: It should be `echo($outp);` without that handlebar.

Comment: All my Network statuses are coming back as 200. Still a blank page

Comment: Ahhhhh get you now! I'm a master in getting little things wrong. Thanks

Comment: Your `ng-app="VinyApp"` should be `ng-app="VinylApp"`

Answer (score 0):

i have solve issue. Please try this code is working g fine for me. here add new angular.min.js and some changes added

```js
var app= angular.module('VinylApp', []);
app.controller('VinylListController', function($scope, $http){
  $http.get("db_con.php")
  .then(function(response){
    $scope.vinyls = response.data;     
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en" ng-app="VinylApp"> 
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">    
      <title>Vinyl Record Store</title> 
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.24/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="app.js"></script>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
      
   </head>
   <body ng-app="VinyApp">
     <div  ng-controller="VinylListController">
       <table>
         <tr ng-repeat="vinyl in vinyls">
           <td>{{vinyl.Vinyl_ID}}</td>
           <td>{{vinyl.VinylName}}</td>
           <td>{{vinyl.Artist}}</td>
           <td>{{vinyl.Price}}</td>
         </tr>
       </table>
     </div> 
   </body> 
 </html>
 
 
 <?php 
  
  $conn = new mysqli("localhost","root", "", "pinakin_northwind");
  $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM vinyl");
  $outp = array();
  while( $rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  $outp[] = $rs;
  }
 echo json_encode($outp); 
?>
```